# Alertify JS confirm not working with button link

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, alertify, alertifyjs

I had a problem when using alertify JS confirm.
when I click the button, alertify confirm does not appear, but immediately redirects to the link. The following script link button and alertify confirm script.

```
function CheckDelete(){
alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog.",
  function(){
    alertify.success('Ok');
  },
  function(){
    alertify.error('Cancel');
  });}

<a href="http://google.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="return CheckDelete();"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</button></a>
```

check in : https://jsfiddle.net/r2fs0p45/

Supposedly when I clicked the button, confirm dialog should appears and then go to the link. but according to my code above, when I click the button, It directly redirect to the link, so confirm dialog does not appear.
Does anyone know how to overcome it?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of the same ? Unable to test it out...

Comment: Why `button` in `<a>` tag ? It will invoke both the actions..Click as well as `redirection`

Comment: Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/6zNaP/89/ ?

Comment: so what is the solution friend?

Answer (score 2):

`CheckDelete()` needs to return `false` to prevent the default action

```
function CheckDelete(){
    alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog.",
        function(){
            alertify.success('Ok');
        },
        function(){
            alertify.error('Cancel');
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works, but after I click OK, do not go to the link.
how to go to the link after I click OK?

Comment: @RayonDabre handled that in his answer.  `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

> Do not have `button` in `a` tag in your markup.

To navigate user, on `OK` button callback, use `window.location.href` to redirect user.

Try this:

```js
function CheckDelete() {
  alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog.",
    function(input) {
      if (input) {
        alertify.success('Ok');
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
      } else {
        alertify.error('Cancel');
      }
    });
}
```

```css
.alertify,
.alertify-show,
.alertify-log {
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  /* easeOutBack */
}
.alertify-hide {
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  -moz-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  -ms-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  -o-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}
.alertify-log-hide {
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  -ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}
.alertify-cover {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.alertify-cover-hidden {
  display: none;
}
.alertify {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: -215px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.alertify-hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -150px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -150px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -150px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -150px);
  transform: translate(0, -150px);
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
/* overwrite display: none; for everything except IE6-8 */

:root *> .alertify-hidden {
  display: block;
}
.alertify-logs {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5000;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
.alertify-logs-hidden {
  display: none;
}
.alertify-log {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  right: -300px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.alertify-log-show {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.alertify-log-hide {
  -webkit-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  transform: translate(300px, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.alertify-dialog {
  padding: 25px;
}
.alertify-resetFocus {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
.alertify-inner {
  text-align: center;
}
.alertify-text {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.alertify-buttons {} .alertify-button,
.alertify-button:hover,
.alertify-button:active,
.alertify-button:visited {
  background: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  /* line-height and font-size for input button */
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.alertify-isHidden {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .alertify,
  .alertify-logs {
    width: 90%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .alertify {
    left: 5%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
/**
 * Twitter Bootstrap Look and Feel
 * Based on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
 */

.alertify,
.alertify-log {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.alertify {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #8E8E8E;
  /* browsers that don't support rgba */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding;
  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
}
.alertify-dialog {
  padding: 0;
}
.alertify-inner {
  text-align: left;
}
.alertify-message {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: Black;
}
.alertify-text-wrapper {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.alertify-text {
  color: #555;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}
.alertify-text:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, .8);
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, .6);
}
.alertify-buttons {
  padding: 8px 15px 8px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #FFF;
  text-align: right;
}
.alertify-button,
.alertify-button:hover,
.alertify-button:focus,
.alertify-button:active {
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
.alertify-button:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #2B72D5;
}
.alertify-button:active {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.alertify-button-cancel,
.alertify-button-cancel:hover,
.alertify-button-cancel:focus,
.alertify-button-cancel:active {
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  color: #333;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E6E6E6);
}
.alertify-button-cancel:hover,
.alertify-button-cancel:focus,
.alertify-button-cancel:active {
  background: #E6E6E6;
}
.alertify-button-ok,
.alertify-button-ok:hover,
.alertify-button-ok:focus,
.alertify-button-ok:active {
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  background-color: #04C;
  border: 1px solid #04C;
  border-color: #04C #04C #002A80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #FFF;
}
.alertify-button-ok:hover,
.alertify-button-ok:focus,
.alertify-button-ok:active {
  background: #04C;
}
.alertify-log {
  background: #D9EDF7;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3A8ABF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border: 1px solid #BCE8F1;
}
.alertify-log-error {
  color: #B94A48;
  background: #F2DEDE;
  border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
}
.alertify-log-success {
  color: #468847;
  background: #DFF0D8;
  border: 1px solid #D6E9C6;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/assets/js/lib/alertify/alertify.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="CheckDelete();"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</button>
```